# Illegal Offset Warning Fix

Tags: php

Trying to fix an illegal offset warning in PHP.

Below is the code that the error is being reported from.

```
foreach ( $xml->{'nowplaying-info'} as $song ) :

foreach ( $song->property as $property ) :

  foreach ( $property->attributes() as $b => $a ) :

    switch ( $a ) :
      case 'cue_title':
          $name = 'title';
          break;
      case 'track_artist_name':
          $name = 'artist';
          break;
      default:
          $name = $a;
    endswitch;

    if ( $name ) :
      $prop = strip_tags( $property->asXML() );
      if ( $name === 'title' || $name === 'artist' ) :
        $prop = ucwords( strtolower( $prop ) );
      endif;
      $property_output[$name] = $prop;
    endif;

  endforeach;

endforeach;

$property_output['time'] = strip_tags( $song['timestamp'][0] );
$song_data[] = $property_output;

endforeach;
```

It appears to not like this line :

```
$property_output[$name] = $prop;
```

Appreciate the help on this.

Comment: What's in `$a` when it doesn't match the cases in your switch statement?

Comment: Where in your code is `$property_output` defined?

Answer (score 0):

$a is probably **array** or **object**.

From http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php:
*Arrays and objects can not be used as keys. Doing so will result in a warning: Illegal offset type.*